# Problema a cargar un RecyclerView con datos de Firebase (No setter/field)

Tags: firebase, recyclerview

Necesito llenar un recyclerview con los datos que tengo almacenados en FireBase pero no lo consigo y no soy capaz de encontrar el error.

El json de firebase

```
"aviso" : {
"-LT9trd7ej8aLhPlDVsM" : {
  "latitud" : 37.7,
  "longitud" : -122.0999983,
  "usuario" : "login2"
},
"-LT9ty7hc9si6x2IempD" : {
  "latitud" : 37.7,
  "longitud" : -122.0999983,
  "usuario" : "login2"
},
"correoprueba" : {
  "latitud" : 0,
  "longitud" : 0,
  "usuario" : "correoprueba"
},
"login2" : {
  "latitud" : 32,
  "longitud" : -122.0999983,
  "usuario" : "login2"
}
},
"chat" : {
"-LT9WsU8whS5ZPONAosl" : {
  "fotoPerfil" : "",
  "hora" : 1544217397371,
  "mensaje" : "hola que tal",
  "nombre" : "Hola ",
  "typemensaje" : "1"
```

}
}

Este es mi adapter

```
public class AdapterUsuario extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterUsuario.UsuarioHolder>{

List<Aviso> avisos;
Context context;

public AdapterUsuario(List<Aviso> avisos) {
    this.avisos = avisos;
}

@Override
public UsuarioHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_aviso,parent,false);
    UsuarioHolder holder=new UsuarioHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UsuarioHolder holder, int position) {
    Aviso user = avisos.get(position);
    holder.latitud.setText(String.valueOf(user.getLatitud()));
    holder.longitud.setText(String.valueOf(user.getLongitud()));
    //holder.getNombre().setText(listMensaje.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.usuario.setText(user.getUsuario());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return avisos.size();
}

public static class UsuarioHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView usuario,longitud,latitud;
    public UsuarioHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        usuario=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUsuario);
        longitud=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLongitud);
        latitud=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLatitud);
    }
}
}
```

Objeto

```
public class Aviso {
private Double latitud;
private Double longitud;
private String usuario;

public Aviso() {
}

public Aviso(Double latitud, Double longitud, String usuario) {
    this.latitud = latitud;
    this.longitud = longitud;
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public Double getLatitud() {
    return latitud;
}

public void setLatitud(Double latitud) {
    this.latitud = latitud;
}

public Double getLongitud() {
    return longitud;
}

public void setLongitud(Double longitud) {
    this.longitud = longitud;
}

public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
```

}

Este es el activity

```
public class AvisosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView rv;
List<Aviso> aviso;
AdapterUsuario adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_avisos);

    rv= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvAvisos);

    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    aviso=new ArrayList<>();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    adapter = new AdapterUsuario(aviso);

    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    database.getReference().getRoot().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            aviso.removeAll(aviso);
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot:
                    dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Aviso user = snapshot.getValue(Aviso.class);
                aviso.add(user);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

Muchas gracias, estoy bloqueado con este tema

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.  ¿Dónde es el error? ¿Podrías poner el mensaje de error que te muestra completo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta pedir los datos en el for ya que

`aviso.add(user);` no le setea los valores al modelo que necesitas

para eso hace lo siguiente

```
  for (DataSnapshot snapshot:
                    dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Aviso user = snapshot.getValue(Aviso.class);
                user.setLatitud(user.getLatitud());
                user.setLongitud(user.getLongitud());
                user.setUsuario(user.getUsuario());
                aviso.add(user);
            }
```

Ademas la referencia que tomas esta mal ya que `database.getReference().getRoot().` te va a devolver el nodo raiz y no el nodo donded estas buscando los datos, para buscar los datos deberias ir a donde estan esos datos que seteas en el modelo

```
database.getReference().child("aviso").child(ID).addValueEventListener...
```

donde .`child(ID)` es el nodo que queres buscar esos datos dentro de aviso

Comment: Me ha resuelto el problema, muchisimas gracias.